# GTK+ 3, C, C++ - Create button with stock image

Tags: c++, c, gtk, deprecated

I was reading the GTK+ 3 reference about the function [`gtk_button_new_from_stock`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkButton.html#gtk-button-new-from-stock). There is this part:

> `gtk_button_new_from_stock` has been deprecated since version 3.10 and
>   should not be used in newly-written code. Use
>   `gtk_button_new_with_label()` instead.

Then, I read the reference about `gtk_button_new_with_label()`, but there is no word about the possibility of creating a button from stock.

I've tried using

```
gtk_button_new_with_label("gtk-media-play");
```

but I only get a button with the label `gtk-media-play`.
Any way, when I use

```
gtk_button_new_from_stock("gtk-media-play");
```

I obtain what I want but I have also a lot of warnings about deprecation.

How do I use the suggested function `gtk_button_new_with_label` in order to obtain a button with stock image?
How can I solve this situation without using deprecated functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stock items in general have been deprecated. You probably want [new_from_icon_name()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkButton.html#gtk-button-new-from-icon-name) instead (I think the documentation should actually refer to that). There's a [standard for icon names](http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/icon-naming-spec-latest.html#names).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think that the official GTK+ reference is ambiguous and should be improved